# I keep getting gt; when using substring or slice

Tags: javascript

I'm building a video player with playlist and using symbol ">" to indicate which video is currently playing. I have the following function:

```
player.onended = function () {
        pl.childNodes[curVideo + 1].childNodes[0].innerHTML = pl.childNodes[curVideo + 1].childNodes[0].innerHTML.slice(1);
        ++curVideo;
        if (playlist.length == 0) {
            player.setAttribute("src", "");
        }
        else if (curVideo < playlist.length) {
            player.setAttribute("src", playlist[curVideo]);
            pl.childNodes[curVideo + 1].childNodes[0].innerHTML = ">" + pl.childNodes[curVideo + 1].childNodes[0].innerHTML;
        } else {
            curVideo = 0;
            player.setAttribute("src", playlist[curVideo]);
            pl.childNodes[curVideo + 1].childNodes[0].innerHTML = ">" + pl.childNodes[curVideo + 1].childNodes[0].innerHTML;
        }
    }
```

I'm not changing this string anywhere else in the code, but when I delete this ">" with slice or substring instead of getting string without it I get this symbol replaced by "gt;".

Before deletion:

```
>htt://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerFun.mp4
```

After deletion:

```
gt;htt://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerFun.mp4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assuming that `>` will come back to you as `>`. It isn't in your example, it's coming back to you as the [named character reference](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#named-character-references) `&gt;` instead. Remember, [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) is HTML. It's not strictly necessary to use a named character entity for `>` in most cases, but it's not uncommon.

This may or may not be reliable cross-browser, so to remove it, I'd probably do this if you need to work with `innerHTML`:

```
l.childNodes[curVideo + 1].childNodes[0].innerHTML =
    pl.childNodes[curVideo + 1].childNodes[0].innerHTML.replace(/^(?:>|\&gt;)/, "");
// ----------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

...which will remove it at the beginning of the string whether it comes back as `>` or `&gt;`.

Alternately, use [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText) or [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent), so you're not dealing with HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by using innerText property instead of innerHTML

Comment: Might be worth [reading on `textContent` to see if it's better suited](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#Differences_from_innerText), particularly the point about page reflows.